# Using DOM to figure out how many images are on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm trying to use the DOM to find out how many images on are my page. I need to write code that will check my page to see how many images there are and store them to a variable. I'm not sure how to write this code but I know you need to search the code for all  tags.

```
<body>
<div id="main_content">

<div id="image_selection">
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</div>

<div id="images">
<h3>Some Images</h3>
    <p><img src="firetruck.jpg" >  |
    <img src="baseball.jpg" >  |
    <img src="soccer_ball.jpg" >
    </p>

</div><!-- end of 'images' div -->
</div><!-- end of 'main content' div -->
```

Comment: You want to store the images to a variable, in what way? The `HTMLImageElement`/`<img>` nodes? The `src` properties? As an array?

Answer (score 3):

`var numberOfImgTags = document.getElementsByTagName('img').length` 
try this.

Comment: He wants to store the images, not the images length.

Answer (score 3):

To find all the `<img>` elements on the page, and assign the resulting `NodeList` to a variable:

```
// (returns live HTMLCollection):
let allImages1 = document.images;
// or (returns (static, non-live) NodeList):
let allImages2 = document.querySelectorAll('img');
// or (returns (live) HTMLCollection):
let allImages3 = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

To find out how many `<img>` elements were found simply access the `length` property of the `NodeList`, for example:

```
let totalNumberOfImages = allImages1.length;
```

To demonstrate the difference between 'live' and 'static' collections:

Using: `document.images`:

```js
let images = document.images,
  counter = document.querySelector('.count');
counter.textContent = images.length;

Array.from(images).forEach(
  (el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      evt.target.remove();
      counter.textContent = images.length;
    });
  })
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
}

span.count {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: limegreen;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<span class="count"></span>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1425yaz0/).

Using `document.querySelectorAll('img')`:

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('img'),
  counter = document.querySelector('.count');
counter.textContent = images.length;

Array.from(images).forEach(
  (el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      evt.target.remove();
      counter.textContent = images.length;
    });
  })
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
}

span.count {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: limegreen;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<span class="count"></span>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1425yaz0/1/).

Using `document.getElementsByTagName('img')`:

```js
let images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
  counter = document.querySelector('.count');
counter.textContent = images.length;

Array.from(images).forEach(
  (el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      evt.target.remove();
      counter.textContent = images.length;
    });
  })
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
}

span.count {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: limegreen;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
<span class="count"></span>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1425yaz0/2/).

Note that we (attempt to) update the count in the same way in each demo, simply accessing the `length` property of the `images` variable; the variable is updated, and is therefore 'live,' when using `document.images` and `document.getElementsByTagName()`, but it remains unchanged, and therefore 'static,' when using `document.querySelectorAll()`:

References:

- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName).
- [`document.images`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/images).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will return a collection of elements that match a selector. That's all you need to just count: `$('img').length`

That's how your current code works:

```
$('img').attr('height','50px').attr('width','50px');
```

This will run an implicit loop over the elements of the collection and set its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

`$('img').length` will give you total count that exist at the time you run it